# BigQuery: Convert DateTime in different time zone to UTC

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to Big Query,
I want to convert the following date-time to UTC timezone.

DateTime format "2021-07-03T23:59:00+04:00[Asia/Dubai]" to UTC.

Thank you.

Comment: was the proposed solution useful, manoj?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert it to TIMESTAMP() without specifying any timezone (since it automatically sets the datetime at UTC) and then convert it back to DATETIME():

```
SELECT
  your_datetime,
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(your_datetime)) AS datetime_utc
FROM
  <your_table>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
your_datetime             datetime_utc
------------------------- -------------------
2021-07-03T23:59:00+04:00 2021-07-03T19:59:00
```